# Magmi - Imported Simple Products Marked "Not Visible Individually" Still Display on Grouped and Configurable Import. 404 when clicked

Tags: magento, magmi

I’ve got Magmi importing both kinds well, but with both grouped and configurable’s simple products still display even though “not visable individually”. I know about the caching thing but the test server I’m on I can’t run command line yet, but if I go into a simple product, save it, and reindex, ALL the products imported will show EXCEPT for the one I saved. It is on the grouped or configurable product.

Below are examples of both my sheets.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Kory

-------------grouped sheet example--------------

```
sku,store,websites,attribute_set,type,categories,weight,price,cost,status,tax_class_id,visibility,manufacturer,name,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword,image,small_image,thumbnail,model,description,short_description,in_depth,qty,is_in_stock
magmi g1,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Group Part 1,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Group Part 1 desc,Group Part 1 short,,10,1
magmi g2,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,10,3,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Group Part 2,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Group Part 2 desc,Group Part 2 short,,10,1
magmi g3,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,8,3,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Group Part 3,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Group Part 3 desc,Group Part 3 short,,10,1
magmi g4,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,10,3,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Group Part 4,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Group Part 4 desc,Group Part 4 short,,10,1
magmi g5,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,12,3,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Group Part 5,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Group Part 5 desc,Group Part 5 short,,10,1
magmi group,,base,Apparel,grouped,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,,,,1,Taxable Goods,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Imported Group,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Imported Group desc,Imported Group short,,0,1
```

--------------End grouped---------------------

--------------configurable example------------

```
sku,store,websites,attribute_set,type,categories,weight,price,cost,status,tax_class_id,apparelcolor,sizeapparel,visibility,manufacturer,name,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword,image,small_image,thumbnail,model,description,short_description,in_depth,qty,is_in_stock,configurable_attributes
magmi c1,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Black,SM,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Black SM Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Black SM Gil Shirt,Black SM Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c2,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Red,SM,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Red SM Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Red SM Gil Shirt,Red SM Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c3,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Blue,SM,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Blue SM Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Blue SM Gil Shirt,Blue SM Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c4,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Black,MD,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Black Med Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Black Med Gil Shirt,Black Med Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c5,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Red,MD,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Red MED Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Red MED Gil Shirt,Red MED Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c6,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Blue,MD,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Blue MED Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Blue MED Gil Shirt,Blue MED Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c7,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Black,LG,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Black LG Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Black LG Gil Shirt,Black LG Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c8,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Red,LG,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Red LG Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Red LG Gil Shirt,Red LG Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi c9,,base,Apparel,simple,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,Blue,LG,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Blue LG Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Blue LG Gil Shirt,Blue LG Gil Shirt short description,,10,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
magmi confi,,base,Apparel,configurable,Apparel/Technical Shirts and Rash Guards/Technical Shirts,1,15,3,1,Taxable Goods,,,"Catalog, Search",Gil,Gil Shirt,,,,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,http://sandbox.apsltd.com.vhost.zerolag.com/images/DG1612silver.jpg,,Gil Shirt,Gil Shirt short description,,0,1,"apparelcolor,sizeapparel"
```

--------------end of configurable example------------

Comment: How did you import the simple products? What were the values under visibility column?

Comment: I did it all on one csv. I set "Perform simples/configurable link" to yes, "auto match simples skus before configurable" to yes, and "Force simples visibility" to yes. On the sheet, however, the simple visibility is set to "Catalog,Search". In the admin the simples are indeed "Not Visible Individually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following numeric values while importing products through Magmi. Then check the results.

```
1 = Not Visible Individually
2 = Catalog
3 = Search
4 = Catalog, Search
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks Muk! Additionally, I just made the simples 1 for "Not Visible Individually" even though I had checked that in Magmi. Just to be safe. Either way, it worked.